# Casting all properties of undefined variables and objects to 0 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have a section of code like the following:

```
var arr = [];

// bit further down in the code
arr[arr.length - 1].id + 1
```

Evidently, if `arr` is empty, then `arr[arr.length - 1]` would return me `undefined`.

Now I know that I can cast that to `0` with a simple or statement like so:

```
arr[arr.length - 1] || 0; // will return 0 if arr[arr.length - 1] is undefined
```

However, I wish to either return `arr[arr.length - 1].id`, or `0`, if `arr[arr.length - 1]` is undefined.

Is there a shorthand notation that I can use to solve this issue? I have tried:

```
arr[arr.length - 1].id || 0
```

However, this returns me an error `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`, which undoubtedly would make sense in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the length first:

```
arr.length && (arr[arr.length - 1].id + 1) || 0;
```

That will evaluate to the last element's "id" value plus 1, or else zero if the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's looking for `.id`, which doesn't exist because the engine is looking for a property of a unknown object. You must first check is `arr` is defined, then proceed the operation:

```
var arr = [];
// It will check for ID only if arr exists and output the result.
// Otherwise value is 0
(arr && arr[arr.length - 1].id) || 0
```